# Quaternion representation of rotations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-groups

How would one show that 1/3 turns correspond to the eight antipodal pairs among the 16 quaternions :
$$
\pm \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{i}{2} \pm \frac{j}{2} \pm \frac{k}{2}
$$
knowing that the rotation about axis u through angle theta corresponds to the quaternion pair $\pm q$ where,
$$
q = \cos(\theta/2) + u \sin(\theta/2)
$$

Comment: Shouldn't this be marked as homework as this is Stillwell's Naive Lie Theory exercise $2.3.5$

Comment: Hint: What can you say about $\theta$, if you know that $\cos(\theta/2)=1/2$?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the original equation, and then take a look at what it means for $\cos(\theta/2)+u\sin(\theta/2)= \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{i}{2} \pm \frac{j}{2} \pm \frac{k}{2}$.

First note that $\pm \frac{i}{2} \pm \frac{j}{2} \pm \frac{k}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}u$ where $u=\pm\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}\pm\frac{j}{\sqrt{3}}\pm\frac{k}{\sqrt{3}}$. It doesn't matter how you pick the signs: it's always a unit vector.

So you are now looking at $\cos(\theta/2)+u\sin(\theta/2)= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}u$. From $\cos(\theta/2)=\frac12$, you learn that $\theta/2\in\{-\pi/3,\pi/3\}$. Given also $\sin(\theta/2)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, we deduce $\theta/2=\pi/3$. This attests that the quaternion rotates by $2\pi/3$, one third of a full turn. Given that you can freely pick the three sets of signs in $u$, that accounts for $8$ quaternions.

The same story holds for $-\frac12$ in front, but these quaternions are precisely $-1$ times the other set of quaternions we discovered. Each of the two sets contains one half of an antipodal pair.

It should also be noted that this does not find *all* $1/3$ turn quaternions, it just finds the ones that rotate about the eight axes $\pm i\pm j\pm k$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write down the rotation matrix explicitly by fixing a basis. Then using the same basis, try to find a quarterion such that its action's corresponding matrix is the same. This should not be difficult since 1/3 rotation has special properties available.

Comment: can u please give some notion as to how to do this? thanks.

Comment: I think you can fix the direction perpendicular to the rotation to be $z$, and treat the rotation in the $xy$-plane first. In the same time fixing a basis for the quarterions using $x,y,z$. Since $z$ coordinate is not changed, the computation should follow in the same way as the 2D case.

Comment: wouldn't this rotation be in R4, instead of R3? How would that yield the eight antipodal pairs?

Comment: Yes, in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ case you can do more by fixing $z,w$ to be the plane perpendicular to the rotation and the computation would be simplified. The (computation) would be leaved to you.

Comment: Dear @BobHsu : This "polar representation" is most commonly used to perform $3D$ rotations on the $3D$ space of pure quaternions via the map $v\mapsto qvq^{-1}$. The same map works on the full set of quaternions too, it's just that the real axis is fixed anyway, and the only thing that changes is the space of pure quaternions. So it can be considered a rotation of both $\Bbb R^4$ and $\Bbb R^3$.